# get encrypt key MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, encryption, password-encryption

I have a table whose data has been encrypted
I forgot the key used to encrypt data
how do I know the key used in my table?

select aes_decrypt (unhex ("905650A03048950FA2EF67837425E8E6"), "key") from user_tbl

Comment: Hmmm... Isn't being unable to do that the whole point of encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot decipher without the key.

The only way is to **find out what was the key**.

Or wait for some genious out there to break the algorithm. Can take decades or never happen.

I'm sorry I don't have any other answer to give you.